# Get each user role in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a DB and in this DB I have a users table and a groups table where each user is related to a specific group.

In the groups table we have a “data entry” group, a “reviewer” group, an “approver” group etc.

Now assume a user X. This user is added to the “data entry” group and also added to the “reviewer” group, that means the user X has both access rights: data entry and reviewer.

Y is another user who has the “data entry” access right, so when I want to generate a report to get the count for each user and group, the “data entry” user and the “data entry + reviewer” user must be counted separately.

The point here is that those users which belong to both groups must not be counted in the individual groups; for example the “data entry + reviewer” user must not be counted to the “data entry” group.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: this is my query which i want to select data from db-                                        select distinct on (login) login ,organization,g.name,
case when g.gid=2302 then 'Data_Entry' else '' end,
case when g.gid=2303 then 'Reviewer' else '' end,
case when g.gid=2304 then 'Approver' else '' end,
case when g.gid in(2304,2303) then 'Reviewer+Approver' else '' end
from user u
left join groups as g on g.uid=u.id
where g.id in (2304,2303,2302)
and lower(u.login) in
('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w')

Answer (score 0):

I'd aggregate twice - first, for each user get all the groups he or she belongs too, and then aggregate that result and count how many each combination appears:

```
-- Count how many times each combination occurs
SELECT   group_combinataions, COUNT(*) 
FROM     (-- Get the groups for each user
          SELECT   STRING_AGG(group_name ORDER BY group_name) AS group_combinations 
          FROM     groups
          GROUP BY userid) t
GROUP BY group_combinations
```